# Oracle Apex Image Component seems to be escaping the ITEM SOURCE

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When I create my Image item in Apex 5 I am setting my source to be "Static Value" and am using this substitution string.

```
#APP_IMAGES#images/servlet.png
```

However, the HTML it is outputting seems to be escaped, and the image is not being returned in the rendered page.

The items is set up as "Image URL based on page item value" and then I am using a Static value with a substitution string.

```
<img  id="P2_NEW" class="display_image"  src="ariel_apex_apps&#x2F;r&#x2F;104&#x2F;files&#x2F;static&#x2F;v2&#x2F;images&#x2F;servlet.png" alt="Test&#x20;Image" title="Test&#x20;Image">
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your source should be just:

```
#APP_IMAGES#servlet.png
```

Comment: but when I uploaded the image as a static application file I specified "images" as the folder?  In fact I took the value "APP_IMAGES#images/servlet.png" straight from my list of static files presented back to me after the upload.

Comment: OK, but you keep omitting the leading # in your example, is that the issue?  It should be `#APP_IMAGES#images/servlet.png`

Comment: my apologies, this is what I am adding in the Static Value field:  #APP_IMAGES#images/servlet.png which I am copying from the shared components list itself.  Not sure why the leading hash got dropped, but I am entering with a forward #.